# Are there closed hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with negative mean curvature (not necessarily constant)?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Are there closed hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. the boundary of a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$) with negative mean curvature (not necessarily constant)?

Comment: Think about the shape of the hypersurface at an extreme point, i.e. a point maximizing the distance to (some choice of) the origin.